# Why does Tor Browser auto-reset DisableNetwork setting to 1 after Tor Browser Exit?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows, error

1.) Why does my Tor Browser auto-reset the `DisableNetwork` setting to "1" after Tor Browser shutsdown for a clean "Exit"?

2.) How should I stop this settings auto-reset behavior so I do not have to re-edit the `torrc` configuration file every time I want to start Tor Browser?

3.) Does my manually resetting `DisableNetwork` to 0 before I restart Tor Browser harm my Tor online security settings in any way?

I run WinXP Home SP3 with local Administrator rights & the latest MS patches are up to date with the latest Tor Browser version 5.5.1.  As far as I know, the McAfee Anti-Virus software I have installed does not interfere with Tor Browser or its settings.  I have enabled the MS Security Center to enable ports 80, 443 for Tor Browser and `obsf4` use.

Whenever I successfully open Tor Browser and eventually close Tor when I am finished, the `DisableNetwork` setting always auto-resets from 0 to 1 for no apparent reason.  All other Tor Browser settings and changes are correctly saved, but not the `DisableNetwork` setting.  No file or app error is listed in the WinXP system/app event log and `DisableNetwork` is not located in Firefox's `about:config`.  The only Tor Browser listing for `DisableNetwork` is in `torrc` settings file.  This unannounced `DisableNetwork` settings change prevents me from restarting Tor Browser unless I manually edit the `Torrc` file.

As a result, I only have 2 or 3 options to successfully restart Tor Browser.

The first option is to edit the text file `c:\documents and settings\test user\desktop\tor browser\browser\torbrowser\data\tor\torrc` to change the `DisableNetwork` setting from 1 to 0.  Tor Browser will then run correctly after I make the `DisableNetwork` setting change. However `DisableNetwork` will later change back 1 when the Tor app is closed.

The second option is more tedious & time consuming, where I have to reinstall Tor Browser through a TorProject.org update or upgrade. Upon successful startup, I then have to reconfigure Tor Browser as if it is a totally new install of the software.

A third option after Tor Browser shutdown could be to create a batch file to copy a pre-saved `torrc` file that includes `DisableNetwork 0` to overwrite the original `torrc` file.  However, this is a temporary workaround and not a solution to why the `DisableNetwork` setting changes.

Any suggestion would be appreciated!  I have experienced this same `DisableNetwork` settings problem when using Tor for the past several years...